# How to read and print unique coordinates(x,y) from an array of struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an array of structures containing an index and coordinates (x, y e.g 0,0: 1,2: 0,0), I want to print only unique indexes and coordinate points points from this array, so far I have

```
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTS 1000

struct fixation_point_type {
    int id_number;
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct fixation_point_type fixation_point_types[MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTS];

{
    cordinate[N].id_number;
    cordinate[N].x;
    cordinate[N].y;
    N++;
```

The expected output should be a unique index and coordinates.
If the the coordinates are:

```
715 242
695 241
695 241
```

the expected output will be:

```
715 242
695 241
```

Comment: Please show an mcve

Comment: Your spec is really unclear, show at least an example of expected output.

Comment: I am reading the input from a file and storing the cordinates in an array of struct,the expected input and output should be as shown if the the cordinates are 
1 715 242
2 695 241
3 695 241 
the expected output will be
1 715 242
2 695 241

Comment: How large can `N` be? 1000s, 1000000s?  Post what you have tried.

Comment: N is a max of 1000

Answer (score 1):

To be honest not tested.

```
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTS 500

typedef struct 
{
    int id_number;
    int x;
    int y;
}fixation_point_type ;
fixation_point_type sf[MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTS];

int find_in_array(int (*arr)[2], int x, iny y, size_t size)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        if(*arr[0] == x && *arr[1] == y)
        {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
        arr++;
    }
    return result;
}

void print_distinct(fixation_point_type *fp, size_t elements)
{
    size_t arrsize = 0;
    int fd[MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTS][2];

    for(size_t index = 0; index < MAX_NUMBER_OF_POINTS; index++)
    {
        if(!find_in_array(&fd[0], sf[index].x, sf[index].y, arrsize))
        {
            fd[arrsize][0] = fp[index].x;
            fd[arrsize][1] = fp[index].y;
            arrsize++;
            printf("Index: %d, X:%d, Y:%d\n", fp[index].id_number, fp[index].x, fp[index].y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, code creation from an almost empty spec, congrat. Just a typo : `iny y` rather than `int y`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to print unique coordinates in the array of structures:

```
size_t print_coordinates(const fixation_point_type *array, size_t size) {
    size_t i, j, count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (array[i].x == array[j].x && array[i].y == array[j].y) {
                /* found a duplicate */
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == j) {
            /* no duplicates: print the coordinates */
            printf("%d %d\n, array[i].x, array[i].y);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```